# Linked Lists - Global v. Local Variables

Tags: c, linked-list, global-variables

I have the following algorithm which is meant to reverse a linked list.

```
typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
}LL_t;

void insert(LL_t** head, int value) 
{
    LL_t* new_node = (LL_t*) malloc(sizeof(LL_t)); 
    new_node->data  = value; 
    new_node->next = (*head); 
    (*head)    = new_node;
}

LL_t* head;
// Post: L contains the data in the original L, but in the reverse order.
void reverse(LL_t * L) {
    LL_t *current, *prev, *next;
    current = head;
    prev = NULL;
    while ( current != NULL )
    {
        next = current->next;
        current->next = prev;
        prev = current;
        current = next;  
    }   
    head = prev;
}

int main ()
{
struct node* L = NULL;
insert( &L, 42 );
insert( &L, 36 );
insert( &L, 14 );
insert( &L, 17 );
insert( &L, 48 );
insert( &L, 36 );

print(L);
printf("\n");
reverse(L);
print(L);

return 0;
}
```

The lists appear as identical when printed both before and after the reverse function. I believe that I have accidentally used local variables to modify my list, whereas I would like to directly modify the list (L). Output:

```
36 48 17 14 36 42
36 48 17 14 36 42
```

How does one directly modify a linked list using global variables?

Comment: What is `print(L);`?

Comment: Simply a function which prints the linked list. I left out the 'print list' and 'insert element' functions as my problem is with the 'reverse' function.

Comment: in that case, we don't get to see how the `head` is getting populated. :-)

Comment: Please provide a ___[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)___

Comment: Thanks, my insert function is now added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is you are passing the pointer by value to the function reverse and the pointer `l` is still pointing to the first element and not to the last element as you think after exiting from the reverse function ,you need to pass the pointer by reference and change the head of the list as shown below:

```
void reverse(LL_t **L) {
    LL_t *current, *prev, *next;
    current = *L;
    prev = NULL;
    while ( current != NULL )
    {
        next = current->next;
        current->next = prev;
        prev = current;
        current = next;  
    }
    head = prev;   
    *L = head;
}
```

call should be

```
reverse(&L);
```

Make this change and now call

`print(L)` and see that you get a reversed linked-list.

---

If you have a fixed protoype like what you said in your comment then go for

```
void reverse(LL_t *L) {
    LL_t *current, *prev, *next;
    current = L;
    prev = NULL;
    while ( current != NULL )
    {
        next = current->next;
        current->next = prev;
        prev = current;
        current = next;  
    }   
    head = prev;
}
```

The call should be

```
reverse(L);
```

Then while printing call

```
print(head);
```

Comment: It still seems to print two identical arrays. Does neither the declaration in the first line of main() nor the typedef struct function allow for the use of L as a pointer?

Comment: Your code is perfect. My prof though gave us the task to fill in the function 'void reverse(LL_t * L)' and to call it by 'reverse(L)' which I am finding difficult.

Comment: Much appreciated, thank-you for all the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

```
head = L;//you don't assign to head.
reverse(L);//unused L at reverse.
print(head);
```